# Zend framework Multi Checkbox

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I make the `checkbox` checked in `Zend Framework`. I have the following code for multicheckbox and I want to check my `checkboxes` by default when page loads. I have tried the following code but does not work.

```
$type = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('referenceType');
        $type->addMultiOptions(array('1' => 'payment','2' => 'purchase'));
        $type->setValue(array(1,2));
        $this->addElement($type);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have used setvalue method for default check the checkbox . But by this method my checkboxes not checked when i open page. Please help me.     How i can check my checkboes by deault?

Comment: Which zend version are you using? For zend 1.12 that should do it.